# NSButton's images lose transparency on selection

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I have edited some NSButtons in my Mac OS X application and set a custom image to them. The images are in png format with transparency. When I select a button, the background of the image goes white.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue was that I was customising a 'Bevel' button. I changed the button bezel to 'Square' and changed the button type to 'Momentary Change'.

Hope this helps some people in the future!

Comment: I don't know why, but that fixed my problem also! Thanks!