# NSButtonCell hover image, transparent background on click?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hover, transparency, nsbuttoncell

I've implemented an NSButton with an image in it.

When the user hovers it, the image changes to something else, and then back on.

---

**Normal Status :**

[image]

**On Hover :**

[image]

---

The code I'm using for the `NSButtonCell` is :

**Interface :**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DKHoverButtonCell : NSButtonCell 
{
    NSImage *_oldImage;
    NSImage *hoverImage;
}

@property (retain) NSImage *hoverImage;

@end
```

**Implementation :**

```
#import "DKHoverButtonCell.h"

@interface NSButtonCell()
- (void)_updateMouseTracking;
@end

@implementation DKHoverButtonCell

@synthesize hoverImage;

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (hoverImage != nil && [hoverImage isValid]) {
        _oldImage = [[(NSButton *)[self controlView] image] retain];
        [(NSButton *)[self controlView] setImage:hoverImage];
    }
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_oldImage != nil && [_oldImage isValid]) {
        [(NSButton *)[self controlView] setImage:_oldImage];
        [_oldImage release];
        _oldImage = nil;
    }
}

- (void)_updateMouseTracking {
    [super _updateMouseTracking];
    if ([self controlView] != nil && [[self controlView] respondsToSelector:@selector(_setMouseTrackingForCell:)]) {
        [[self controlView] performSelector:@selector(_setMouseTrackingForCell:) withObject:self];
    }
}

- (void)setHoverImage:(NSImage *)newImage {
    [newImage retain];
    [hoverImage release];
    hoverImage = newImage;
    [[self controlView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_oldImage release];
    [hoverImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

**Now, here is the issue :**

- although the above controls works 100% (with a "X" rounded image, and transparent background"), when the user clicks on it, it displays a "white"-ish background, and not retain my old "transparent" background
- How should I go about resolving this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756312/nsbutton-white-background-when-clicked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801418/nsbuttons-images-lose-transparency-on-selection, would setting the button cell type to "momentary change" be a sufficient solution for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change button's type to ***Momentary Change***. You can change it in Attributes inspector:

[image: how to do it]

Or change programatically:

```
[button setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
```

Comment: I knew it was something dead simple... It was just one of those cases when I simply couldn't figure out what. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @JustinBoo: if you can help me plzzz..  [My question similar to above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012187/how-to-set-background-color-while-selecting-row-of-nsoutlineview)

Answer (score 0):

But for your case it should be sufficient to use `showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside` property of `NSButtonCell` which has been around since the beginning (OS X 10.0). This would show the button's border only when the mouse is hovering inside the button. Combine that with a border style that is filled and light gray, it would be pretty close to the result you've achieved.

There's no subclassing required nor using undocumented API functions (in your case, `_updateMouseTracking`).

```
closeButton.bezelStyle = .inline
closeButton.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)

if let buttonCell = closeButton.cell as? NSButtonCell {
    buttonCell.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = true
}
```